# OpenAi Codex: Is the 'best_of' parameter related to the nucleus sampling?

Tags: python, openai-api

The code below sets Codex to use nucleus sampling with top_p = 0.9. I know this means Codex samples from the tokens comprising the top 90% probability mass at each step.

```py
response = openai.Completion.create(
  model="code-davinci-002",
  prompt= "##### Fix bugs in the below function\n \n### Buggy Python\nimport Random\na = random.randint(1,12)\nb = random.randint(1,12)\nfor i in range(10):\n    question = \"What is \"+a+\" x \"+b+\"? \"\n    answer = input(question)\n    if answer = a*b\n        print (Well done!)\n    else:\n        print(\"No.\")\n    \n### Fixed Python",
  max_tokens=128,
  top_p=0.9,
  temperature = 0.8,
  n = 5,
# best_of=10
}
```

I noticed tha codex has another parameter called 'best_of'. The [documentation](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-best_of) explains it as: *Generates `best_of` completions server-side and returns the "best" (the one with the highest log probability per token). When used with `n`, best_of controls the number of candidate completions and `n` specifies how many to return – best_of must be greater than `n`.*

I think that `best_of` sounds like greedy strategy rather than sampling. When I add `best_of` in the above code (still keep the top_p), Codex can successfully return 5 completions. My question is: How does `best_of` work with `top_p`? Are they relevant?